# hibernate Mapping exception even though it is configured in hibernate.cfg

Tags: hibernate

I am getting an exception saying "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.with.annotations.AddressAsValueObject. But I was having this entry in my hibernate.cfg.xml as `<mapping class="com.with.annotations.AddressAsValueObject">`.

```
@Embeddable 
public class AddressAsValueObject {
//All attributes here..
}

@Entity 
@Table (name="USER_WITH_V_ADDRESS")
public class UserDetailsWithAddressValueObject {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "USER_NAME")
private String name;

@Embedded
private AddressAsValueObject addressObj;

@Column(name = "USER_DOB")
private String dob;
 }
```

### client class to save them to DB:

```
UserDetailsWithAddressValueObject userDetailsWithAddressValueObject = new          UserDetailsWithAddressValueObject();
    userDetailsWithAddressValueObject.setName("XXX-WITH-ADDRESS");
    userDetailsWithAddressValueObject.setDob("JUN6");

    AddressAsValueObject addressValueObject = new AddressAsValueObject();
    addressValueObject.setCity("PUNE");
    addressValueObject.setStreet("XXXX");
    addressValueObject.setPin("XXXXX");
    userDetailsWithAddressValueObject.setAddressObj(addressValueObject);

    session1.save(addressValueObject);
    session1.save(userDetailsWithAddressValueObject);
```

I am getting mapping exception with this. Please help me to resolve this error?

Comment: would be nice if you posted the stackTrace()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to save an instance of `AddressAsValueObject`. But `AddressAsValueObject` is not an entity. It's an embeddable class. It can not be saved on its own. Only as part (embedded) of an actual entity.

Remove the call to

```
session1.save(addressValueObject);
```

Comment: Hi, I have some question around this.. Whats the difference between elementcollection and jointable? Without having elementcollection ,can jointable be used to build foreignkey relation ? how these two are inetrrelated? please help me to understand. thanks